# C++ map of heterogeneous function

Tags: c++, dictionary

I would like to create a C++ script that uses `map` to execute heterogeneous functions, and stores the input/output in a `map`.
To deal with the heterogeneity I though to use the `any` type.
However, this creates problems, since the function pointer is not able to convert other type in `any` type.

Here is a minimal example that is not working, but illustrates what I would like to do:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

string funct1(int a, int b)
{  
  int c= a+b;
  string name = to_string(c);
  return name ;
}

float funct2(int a, int b)
{
  // float b2
  float c=a-b;
  return c ;
}

int main(void) 
{ 
  cout << "START" << endl;

  std::map<std::string, std::any> ListObjIn; // 
  std::map<std::string, std::any> ListObjOut; // 
  typedef std::any (*FnPtr)(std::any, int);  
  std::map<std::string, FnPtr> ListCommand; // 
  // 
  ListObjIn["a1"] = 1;
  ListObjIn["a2"] = 1.5;
  ListCommand["do1"]= funct1;
  ListCommand["do2"]= funct2;

  // ListObjOut["res1"]= ListCommand["do1"]( std::any_cast<int>(ListObjIn["a1"]), 2); 
  ListObjOut["res1"]= ListCommand["do1"]( ListObjIn["a1"], 2);
  cout << "RESULT 1=" << std::any_cast<string>(ListObjOut["res1"]) << endl;

  ListObjOut["res2"]= ListCommand["do2"]( ListObjIn["a2"], 2);
  cout << "RESULT 2=" << std::any_cast<string>(ListObjOut["res2"]) << endl;

  cout << "END" << endl;   
  return(0); 
}
```

I get the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++17 ./test.cpp 
./test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./test.cpp:34:24: error: invalid conversion from ‘std::__cxx11::string (*)(int, int) {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(int, int)}’ to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::any (*)(std::any, int)>::mapped_type {aka std::any (*)(std::any, int)}’ [-fpermissive]
ListCommand["do1"]= funct1;
                    ^~~~~~
./test.cpp:35:24: error: invalid conversion from ‘float (*)(int, int)’ to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::any (*)(std::any, int)>::mapped_type {aka std::any (*)(std::any, int)}’ [-fpermissive]
ListCommand["do2"]= funct2;
                    ^~~~~~
```

I tried to change the input and output type of the function (ie `string` and `float`) to `any`, but this creates problems of conversion at other places.

So it is possible to have something very close to my original example, keeping the heterogeneity of type in/out and map of functions ? Or should think to workaround ? if so, which one ?

Answer (score -1):

You should probably generify return type with std::any:

https://godbolt.org/z/G1EhqY

Comment: In my opinion, use of std::any is a sign of a poor code design. You should consider other ways to implement your algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, your solution success to compile but fails at execution time ! 
If it is poor code design, do you think creating a big mother class from which all the child class would get heritage is better than the std::any approach ? or you have a better option ?

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but I need to know **why** you need to use this design to suggest any solutions?

Comment: I need something like what I describe because I am working on an application that requires to execute functions taking an object (can be any type in a large selection) plus eventually other arguments and returning an object (also varying a lot). And users might execute a sequence (list) of such functions and store outputs.

Comment: Do you have a better solution then ?